# git rebase with the fast forward option enabled

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, fast-forward

Let's say I have a situation like this:

```
a -- b -----------------c -- d -- e   <-- Master
      \
       f ------------l                <-- Branch1
        \           /
         g -- h -- i                  <-- Branch2
```

Where `i` was merged with `f` by using:

```
git merge --no-ff
```

Well, now I want to `rebase` the `Branch1` to the `master`.

If I use `git rebase master Branch1` the result is:

```
a -- b -- c -- d -- e                     <-- Master
                     \
                       f -- g -- h -- i   <-- Branch1
```

It has just merged ignoring my previous `--no-ff`.

**Question**:

Is there an instruction like `git rebase --no_ff ...`?

What I would like to achieve is:

```
a -- b -- c -- d -- e                   <-- Master
                     \
                      f ------------l   <-- Branch1
                       \           /
                        g -- h -- i     <-- Branch2
```

Looking on the web (included stackoverflow) I was not able to find any useful information.

Comment: @adreee No, sorry. The situation seems different and, from the answer there, everything is so confused. I am not able to achieve useful information from the answer you are proposing. Can you? Which is the solution for my problem? In the answer is written "git rebase does not make sense in your case. It just takes your commits and adds them to the new base. In your case the old base seems to be exactly the same as the new base, therefore the result is exactly the same as before. (Only the merge commit is missing.) "

Comment: Try `git rebase -p`: from `git rebase -h`:  -p, --preserve-merges    try to recreate merges instead of ignoring them

Comment: Side note: there is a `--no-ff` option to `git rebase` but it means something very different. You want `--preserve-merges` or `-p`; or if your Git is new enough, the fancy new `--rebase-merges` feature. See [joanis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55652792/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The `-p` option to `git rebase` is intended to solve this problem.

This should work:

```
git rebase -p master Branch1
```

From `git rebase -h`:

```
-p, --preserve-merges
                      try to recreate merges instead of ignoring them
```

**Caveats**

Thanks @andreee for pointing these issues out, documented in `git rebase --help`:

- Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.
- combining `--preserve-merges` with `--interactive` is generally not a good idea

Comment: ...trying. I need to clone again the projects

Comment: Looks like a nice option to solve the problem, but maybe you should also mention the issues related to it, for example _"Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved."_ and _"[...] combining it with the --interactive option explicitly is generally not a good idea [...]"_

Comment: @adreee, Does it mean that the rebase will be succesfullly terminated but the merge conflict will be ignored?

Comment: @Leos313: Unfortunately I don't have experience with that option, credits go to joanis for this. But there seems to be some useful information in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--p).

Comment: I am sorry to say that it does not work. It gives "error: could not apply ... `commit_name`"

Comment: @Leos313: when the rebase fails partway through, it hasn't actually *quit* the rebase, it's merely failed to copy that one commit at this point. Your job as the human operating Git is to fix the problem and use `git rebase --continue` to resume the rebase, or decide that this whole thing is a bad idea and run `git rebase --abort` to terminate the operation and put everything back. This is all quite normal and to be expected, when using rebase.

Comment: Note that after the whole operation finishes—regardless of *how* you do it—you'll have to manually adjust at least one branch name, to point to the new copy-commit that holds either `i` or `l`. The `git rebase` operation will only move the name `Branch1` or the name `Branch2`, not both names.

Comment: @torek,  yes, you are absolutely right. I was looking for a solution that does it automatically. And that doesn't exist apparently.